# User Form Input Error Handling with names and dates

Tags: excel, vba

I have a multipage user form that I want to collect data from the user. The user is prompted to enter a patient name and I need to add an error handle that makes sure the Patient’s name includes a last name and a first name. The name needs to be stored in the spreadsheet such that the first character of the last name and the first character of the first name are upper case and there is a comma and a space between last name and the first name. Where the user enters the patients name is a text box, called txtPatient. I believe I will need some type of string manipulation for both tasks, but I am confused as to how to do it. The name is being stored at the bottom of a list of data already in excel, so when I add the patient name, the rest of their data fills in and adds onto the list which I did by

```
    Private Sub cmdAddPatient_Click()
    Worksheets("Daily Appts").Select
    Me.cboStatus = "Scheduled" 'patients status will only be "treated" when they are added
    With Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) 'used to find the how many rows contain data in worksheet and add on
        .Offset(1, 0) = Me.txtPatient
        .Offset(1, 1) = Me.txtLast4 'offset fills in the corresponding column data for user inputs
        .Offset(1, 2) = Me.txtDOB
        .Offset(1, 3) = Me.cboProcedure
        .Offset(1, 4) = Me.cboSedation
        .Offset(1, 5) = Me.cboStatus
        .Offset(1, 6) = Me.cboAttending
        .Offset(1, 7) = Me.cboFellow
        .Offset(1, 8) = Me.cboNurse
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't have a separate textbox for first and last name. Ideally, you could store the information in separate columns in Excel as well. In my opinion, it's best to use your data store to only store data, not presentation or formatting. When you suggest that the first and last names should be separated by comma, that to me is more of a formatting thing. I'd prefer separate columns, and when needed, you can use `Application.Proper(lastName) & ", " & Application.Proper(firstName)` to join them.

Comment: Adding to @user3561813 's comment, then you can test that the `Trim(value) <> vbNullString` to make sure that the value for each box is not just white space.

Comment: I can't recommend @user3561813's approach enough. I do a lot of data migrations, and name normalization is second only to address normalization in difficulty. Remember, if you give a user a TextBox, you're going to wind up with all sorts of cr@p in there - guaranteed.

Comment: To add to the "go with @user3561813's suggestion" pile ... For fun reading - [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: All of the above is excellent advice. I'd also add, you might want to put something in your `cmdAddPatient` routine that clears out the Patient data *at the very least*, preventing someone accidentally clicking [Add Patient] twice and creating dupe records.